# Trying to resize2fs EB volume fails

Tags: amazon-ec2, diskspace, disk-partitioning

I have a 200GB EBS volume and am trying to increase the space available. I followed the instructions on: http://www.hellersoftware.com/2012/resize-ebs-volume-attached-to-amazon-web-services-ec2-instance/ and managed to create a snapshot and create a new EBS based on that snapshot.

Everything is peachy, except when I do:

`# resize2fs /dev/sdf`

I get

```
resize2fs 1.40.8 (13-Mar-2008)
resize2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdf
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

Not sure what's going on there, but my new volume still only shows 200GB, when in fact it's an 800GB volume.

Comment: what's the output of mount, df -h and fdisk -l /dev/sdf? Are you able to mount the volume?

Comment: I can mount it and `df -h` says:

`/dev/sdf              200G  187G   14G  94% /vol`

` fdisk -l /dev/sdf

Disk /dev/sdf: 858.9 GB, 858993459200 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 104433 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/sdf doesn't contain a valid partition table`

Comment: Are you using the ext filesystem?

Comment: not sure - how would i find out?

Comment: either grep "/dev/sdf" < /etc/fstab or mount the volume and type mount | grep "/dev/sdf"

Comment: `/dev/sdf on /vol type xfs (rw)`

Answer (score 84, accepted):

The OP stated that he was using the XFS filesystem.
The tool `resize2fs` works with ext2, ext3 and ext4 only.

There's a similar tool available for the XFS filesytem called xfs_growfs.
You'll most likely have to install it first

```
sudo yum install xfsprogs.x86_64 --assumeyes
```

then mount your filesystem

```
sudo mount -t xfs /dev/sdf /vol
```

now you can extend the filesystem

```
sudo xfs_growfs /vol
```

`df -h` should now show more available space

I hope this helped :)

Tip: ext4 filesystem is the recommended filesystem for EBS volumes ( for the future )

Comment: xfs_growfs worked for me on centos 7

Comment: `fsadm resize` worked for me

Comment: for some reason i needed to do `sudo growpart /dev/xvda 1` before `sudo xfs_growfs /vol`.